# Watch stylus from package.json

Tags: javascript, stylus

I'm running into a situation where i'm trying to watch my stylus file from my package.json but it's not working the way I'd like it to.  I have the following build script:

`"scripts": {
...
    "watch": "watchify public/components/**/* -o public/bundle.js -dv",
    "watch:css": "stylus -w public/css/styl/style.styl -o public/css/style.css",
  },`

I can run both tasks separately and everything works, but I'd like to run `npm run watch` to handle both tasks but i haven't figured out a way. I prefer not to use a gulp or grunt.  Can someone lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, very simple solution for this:

change this:

```
"scripts": {
...
    "watch": "watchify public/components/**/* -o public/bundle.js -dv",
    "watch:css": "stylus -w public/css/styl/style.styl -o public/css/style.css",
  },
```

to this:

```
"scripts": {
...
    "watch": "watchify public/components/**/* -o public/bundle.js -dv & npm run watch:css",
    "watch:css": "stylus -w public/css/styl/style.styl -o public/css/style.css",
  },
```